# Passing Data from Master to Detail Page

Tags: sapui5

I watched some tutorials about navigation + passing data between views, but it doesn't work in my case.
My goal is to achieve the follwing:

1. On the MainPage the user can see a table with products (JSON file). (Works fine!)
2. After pressing the "Details" button, the Details Page ("Form") is shown with all information about the selection.

The navigation works perfectly and the Detail page is showing up, however the data binding doesnt seem to work (no data is displayed)
My idea is to pass the JSON String to the Detail Page. How can I achieve that? Or is there a more elegant way?

Here is the code so far:

MainView Controller

```
sap.ui.controller("my.zodb_demo.MainView", {

    onInit: function() {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("zodb_demo/model/products.json");

        var mainTable = this.getView().byId("productsTable");
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        mainTable.setModel(oModel);
        mainTable.bindItems("/ProductCollection", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{Name}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{SupplierName}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{Price}"
            })]
        }));
    },

    onDetailsPressed: function(oEvent) {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("productsTable");

        var contexts = oTable.getSelectedContexts();
        var items = contexts.map(function(c) {
            return c.getObject();
        });

        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainApp");
        var page = app.getPage("DetailsForm");

        //Just to check if the selected JSON String is correct
        alert(JSON.stringify(items));


        //Navigation to the Detail Form
        app.to(page, "flip");
    }
});
```

Detail Form View:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.zodb_demo.DetailsForm">
  <Page title="Details" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="goBack">
    <content>
      <f:Form id="FormMain" minWidth="1024" maxContainerCols="2" editable="false" class="isReadonly">
        <f:title>
          <core:Title text="Information" />
        </f:title>
        <f:layout>
          <f:ResponsiveGridLayout labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" />
        </f:layout>
        <f:formContainers>
          <f:FormContainer>
            <f:formElements>
              <f:FormElement label="Supplier Name">
                <f:fields>
                  <Text text="{SupplierName}" id="nameText" />
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
              <f:FormElement label="Product">
                <f:fields>
                  <Text text="{Name}" />
                </f:fields>
              </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
          </f:FormContainer>
        </f:formContainers>
      </f:Form>
    </content>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Detail Form Controller:

```
sap.ui.controller("my.zodb_demo.DetailsForm", {

    goBack: function() {
        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainApp");
        app.back();
    }
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870579/5846045. No need to use EventBus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The recommended way to pass data between controllers is to use the EventBus

```
sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
```

You define a channel and event between the controllers. On your DetailController you subscribe to an event like this:

```
onInit : function() {
    var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    // 1. ChannelName, 2. EventName, 3. Function to be executed, 4. Listener
    eventBus.subscribe("MainDetailChannel", "onNavigateEvent", this.onDataReceived, this);)
},

onDataReceived : function(channel, event, data) {
   // do something with the data (bind to model)
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

And on your MainController you publish the Event:

```
...
//Navigation to the Detail Form
app.to(page,"flip");
var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
// 1. ChannelName, 2. EventName, 3. the data
eventBus.publish("MainDetailChannel", "onNavigateEvent", { foo : "bar" });
...
```

See the documentation here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.EventBus.html#subscribe

And a more detailed example:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/10/25/openui5-sapui5-communication-between-controllers--using-publish-and-subscribe-from-eventbus

Comment: Please note, that the [Component has an eventbus](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html#getEventBus), too. You should use that if you are encapsulating your app in a component. In your controllers it would look like this: `var eventBus = this.getOwnerComponent().getEventBus();`

Answer (score 6):

Even though this question is old, the scenario is still valid today (it's a typical *master-detail* / *n-to-1* scenario). On the other hand, the [currently accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001318/5846045) is not only outdated but also a result of an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

> is there a more elegant way?

Absolutely. Take a look at this ***Flexible Column Layout* tutorial: https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/c4de2df385174e58a689d9847c7553bd**

No matter what control is used (`App`, `SplitApp`, or `FlexibleColumnLayout`), the concept is the same:

1. User clicks on an item from the master.

   1. Get the binding context from the selected item by `getBindingContext(/*modelName*/)`.
   2. Pass only key(s) to the [`navTo`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/methods/navTo) parameters (no need to pass the whole item context).
2. In the "Detail" view:

   1. Attach a handler to the [`patternMatched` event](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route/events/patternMatched) of the navigated route in the Detail controller's `onInit`.
   2. In the handler, create the corresponding key, by which the target entry can be uniquely identified, by accessing the event parameter `arguments` in which the passed key(s) are stored. [In case of OData, use the API `createKey`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016070/5846045)
   3. With the created key, call [`bindObject`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/bindObject) with the path to the unique entry in order to propagate its context to the detail view.
3. The relative binding paths in the detail view can be then resolved every time when the detail page is viewed. As a bonus, this also enables deep link navigation or bookmark capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set local json model to store your data, and use it in the corresponding views. But be sure to initialize or clear it in the right time.