# Receive Data from View through Target SAPUI5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I want to call a second View via the Targets function in my Detail View and also pass Data throught the first to the second View.

```
onListItemPressed: function(evt){
            var id = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("PoNumber");
            this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("MaterialDetailView", {
                data: id
            });
        }
```

This works fine.

But I don't know how to get the passed Data in the second view and bind the data to the View.
I can only find how to do it with a Route but I want to stick with the Target.

Any sugesstions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data from Master to Detail Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000949/passing-data-from-master-to-detail-page)

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870579/5846045

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the data in the onRouteMatched function after you call the second view. And read the data than..

Comment: i tried this but I did not work for me. Maybe I made a mistake. Can you post some code here?

Comment: `onInit: function () {
   var that = this;
   var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(that);
   oRouter.getRoute("Details").attachMatched(that._onRouteMatched, that);},` thats the on init after that the function onRouteMatched will be called and `_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
   var that = this;
   var oView;
   var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   that._oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments"); ` and you in oArgs are stored the data.. depends also on the object but in most cases this works